# MDFloatingActionButton does not resize?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to resize this button to take up most of the container it's in, but for some reason, it doesn't resize. We've tried doing size_hint: None, None and setting size manually, but that didn't work. Here is the code and a screenshot of the app. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZbYz.png)

Python Code:

```
from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial


class MD3Card(MDCard, RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior):
    text = StringProperty()


class KeepUp(MDApp):
    data = {
        'Calendar Settings': 'calendar',
        'Reminder Settings': 'format-list-bulleted',
        'Tasks Settings': 'clipboard-list-outline'
    }

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        Window.maximize()
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.root.ids.three.add_widget(
                MD3Card(
                    line_color=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8),
                    style='elevated',
                    md_bg_color='#FFFFF0',
                    size=(400, 1000)
                )
            )
        self.root.ids.one.add_widget(
            MD3Card(
                line_color=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8),
                    style='elevated',
                    md_bg_color='#FFFFF0',
                    size=(1000, 900)
            )
        )


KeepUp().run()
```

KivyMD Code

```
<MD3Card>
    padding: 16
    size_hint: None, None

    MDRelativeLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.size

MDScreen:

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (228/255.0,228/255.0,194/255.0,255/255.0)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    MDBoxLayout:
        id: three
        adaptive_size: True
        spacing: "30dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .27, "center_y": .5}
    
    MDRelativeLayout:
        size_hint: None,None
        size: root.size
        MDLabel:
            id: Calendars
            text: "Current Calendars"
            font_name: 'Gabriola.ttf'
            font_size: 45
            adaptive_size: True
            color: .2, .2, .2, .8
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.09, "center_y": 0.815}
        MDLabel:
            id: Reminders
            text: "Current Reminders"
            font_name: 'Gabriola.ttf'
            font_size: 45
            adaptive_size: True
            color: .2, .2, .2, .8
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.26, "center_y": 0.815}
        MDLabel:
            id: Tasks
            text: "Current Tasks"
            font_name: 'Gabriola.ttf'
            font_size: 45
            adaptive_size: True
            color: .2, .2, .2, .8
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.41, "center_y": 0.815}
        Image:
            source:'line.png'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.54, "center_y": 0.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, root.height
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False

    MDGridLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .5}
        adaptive_size: True
        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: "plus"
            icon_size: "128sp"
            type: 'large'
            md_bg_color: (83/255.0,129/255.0,93/255.0,255/255.0)
            theme_icon_color: "Custom"
            icon_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
            pos: 215, 640
        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: "plus"
            icon_size: "128sp"
            type: 'large'
            md_bg_color: (83/255.0,129/255.0,93/255.0,255/255.0)
            theme_icon_color: "Custom"
            icon_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
            pos: 650, 640
        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: "plus"
            icon_size: "128sp"
            type: 'large'
            md_bg_color: (83/255.0,129/255.0,93/255.0,255/255.0)
            theme_icon_color: "Custom"
            icon_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
            pos: 1075, 640

    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        data: app.data
        root_button_anim: True
        icon: "cog"
        bg_color_root_button: (83/255.0,129/255.0,93/255.0,255/255.0)
        bg_color_stack_button: (83/255.0,129/255.0,93/255.0,255/255.0)

    MDBoxLayout:
        id: one
        adaptive_size: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .77, "center_y": .5}

    MDRelativeLayout:
        size_hint: None,None
        size: root.size
        MDLabel:
            id: noselect
            text: "    Nothing selected yet.\n Create some calendars,\n            reminders,\nor tasks to stay on track!"
            font_name: 'Gabriola.ttf'
            font_size: 90
            adaptive_size: True
            color: .2, .2, .2, .8
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.77, "center_y": 0.5}
            halaign: "center"
```